# WebTier component is missing from Enterprise Manager Console

Tags: weblogic

I have installed WebTier and OHS on WebLogic. When I run ./opmnctl status, OHS component is showing as 'ALIVE' but the WebTier component is missing from the EM console(UI).

[image: Screenshot of the EM console]

The OHS version is 11g and WebLogic and Fusion MiddleWare are of version 12c.

Is there any solution for bringing the OHS component to the UI?

Any help is appreciated!